# Large table in Latex gets cut off when outputting to PDF?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, pdftex, vertical-alignment, pdf

I haven't worked with much Latex syntax so I'm not quite sure what stylization changes I need to make here.

I have a large piece of Latex as such:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|} \centering

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccccccc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\cline{2-9}
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{NonWhite} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Black.or.African.American} \\
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 factor(ELECTORAL\_TERM)2018 & 0.104$^{***}$ & 0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.103$^{***}$ & $-$0.103$^{***}$ & $-$0.047$^{***}$ & $-$0.047$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.010) & (0.010) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.006) & (0.006) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 factor(ELECTORAL\_TERM)2019 & 0.129$^{***}$ & 0.128$^{***}$ & 0.088$^{***}$ & 0.088$^{***}$ & 0.092$^{***}$ & 0.092$^{***}$ & 0.063$^{***}$ & 0.063$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.011) & (0.011) & (0.009) & (0.010) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 WOMENS\_RIGHTS\_PROTEST & $-$0.016 & $-$0.025 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  & (0.018) & (0.019) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 WOMENS\_RIGHTS\_COUNTERPROTEST &  & 0.052 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  &  & (0.043) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 RACIAL\_PROTEST &  &  & 0.032$^{***}$ & 0.032$^{***}$ &  &  & 0.020$^{***}$ & 0.021$^{***}$ \\
  &  &  & (0.010) & (0.011) &  &  & (0.007) & (0.008) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 RACIAL\_COUNTERPROTEST &  &  &  & 0.001 &  &  &  & $-$0.007 \\
  &  &  &  & (0.039) &  &  &  & (0.028) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 OTHER\_IDENTITY\_PROTEST &  &  &  &  & 0.057 & 0.068 &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  & (0.077) & (0.078) &  &  \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 OTHER\_IDENTITY\_COUNTERPROTEST &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.116 &  &  \\
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.156) &  &  \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 Republican.Party & 0.061$^{***}$ & 0.061$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.027$^{***}$ & 0.027$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 Democratic.Party & 0.386$^{***}$ & 0.386$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.083$^{***}$ & 0.083$^{***}$ \\
  & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.010) & (0.010) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 CIT\_EST\_White & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.0002 & 0.0002 \\
  & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 CIT\_EST\_African\_American & 0.007$^{**}$ & 0.007$^{**}$ & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.0005 & 0.0005 \\
  & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.002) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 CIT\_EST\_NonWhite & 0.014 & 0.014 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 \\
  & (0.011) & (0.011) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 CVAP\_EST\_White & 0.007 & 0.007 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.001 \\
  & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.003) & (0.003) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 CVAP\_EST\_African\_American & $-$0.007 & $-$0.007 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.001 \\
  & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 CVAP\_EST\_NonWhite & $-$0.020 & $-$0.020 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.002 & 0.002 \\
  & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.010) & (0.010) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
 Constant & $-$23.099 & $-$23.099 & 5.245 & 5.245 & 5.244 & 5.241 & 1.899 & 1.898 \\
  & (14.561) & (14.561) & (12.598) & (12.599) & (12.608) & (12.609) & (8.972) & (8.972) \\
  & & & & & & & & \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
Observations & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 \\
R$^{2}$ & 0.778 & 0.778 & 0.660 & 0.660 & 0.659 & 0.659 & 0.664 & 0.664 \\
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.654 & 0.654 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.476 & 0.476 \\
Residual Std. Error & 0.403 (df = 6145) & 0.403 (df = 6144) & 0.348 (df = 6145) & 0.348 (df = 6144) & 0.349 (df = 6145) & 0.349 (df = 6144) & 0.248 (df = 6145) & 0.248 (df = 6144) \\
F Statistic & 6.250$^{***}$ (df = 3448; 6145) & 6.249$^{***}$ (df = 3449; 6144) & 3.452$^{***}$ (df = 3448; 6145) & 3.450$^{***}$ (df = 3449; 6144) & 3.443$^{***}$ (df = 3448; 6145) & 3.442$^{***}$ (df = 3449; 6144) & 3.524$^{***}$ (df = 3448; 6145) & 3.523$^{***}$ (df = 3449; 6144) \\
\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{8}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{longtable} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The outputted PDF, however, looks like this:

[image]

Where both the bottom and right side of the table are cut off. I tried using longtable as you can see, but that doesn't seem to do much. I'm not sure if I need to rotate the table, or shift the table right, or allow for extra pages, or what.

Comment: Welcome. Maybe you can use abbreviations for your first column and replace the `&&&&&&&&` with a horizontal line. Additionally, regarding your volume of data, you may cannot avoid it to use the longtable function and fill more than one page. Beside this, you don't need a `center` environment, since you already use `\centering`.

Comment: By horizontal line you just mean a single dash like such "-"? Also, I'm fine with filling more than one page. But it just cuts off and never spills anything over to the next page.

Comment: For the splitting of your table using `longtable` you also have to tell latex where to split. You may have a look at the documentation (http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several ways to fit the table on the margin of the page and now I came up with this solution

[image]

I used `longtable` and defined the header, which was missing in your approach; `makecell` can be used for some linebreaks. Also, I had to use `landscape` for fitting the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lm{2cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}@{}}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Dependent variable:} \\* \cmidrule(l){2-9}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{NonWhite} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Black.or.African.American} \\*
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\*
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead
            %
            \multicolumn{9}{c}%
            {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{8}{l}{Dependent variable:} \\* \cmidrule(l){2-9}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{NonWhite} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Black.or.African.American} \\*
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\*
            \midrule
            \endhead
            %
            \endfoot
            %
            \endlastfoot
            %
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{factor(ELECTORAL\_ \\ TERM)2018}} & 0.104$^{***}$ & 0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.103$^{***}$ & $-$0.103$^{***}$ & $-$0.047$^{***}$ & $-$0.047$^{***}$ \\
            & (0.010) & (0.010) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.006) & (0.006) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{factor(ELECTORAL\_ \\ TERM)2019}} & 0.129$^{***}$ & 0.128$^{***}$ & 0.088$^{***}$ & 0.088$^{***}$ & 0.092$^{***}$ & 0.092$^{***}$ & 0.063$^{***}$ & 0.063$^{***}$ \\
            & (0.011) & (0.011) & (0.009) & (0.010) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{WOMENS\_RIGHTS\_ \\ PROTEST}} & $-$0.016 & $-$0.025 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
            & (0.018) & (0.019) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{WOMENS\_RIGHTS\_ \\ COUNTERPROTEST}} &  & 0.052 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
            &  & (0.043) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{RACIAL\_ \\ PROTEST}} &  &  & 0.032$^{***}$ & 0.032$^{***}$ &  &  & 0.020$^{***}$ & 0.021$^{***}$ \\
            &  &  & (0.010) & (0.011) &  &  & (0.007) & (0.008) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{RACIAL\_ \\ COUNTERPROTEST}} &  &  &  & 0.001 &  &  &  & $-$0.007 \\
            &  &  &  & (0.039) &  &  &  & (0.028) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{OTHER\_IDENTITY\_ \\ PROTEST}} &  &  &  &  & 0.057 & 0.068 &  &  \\
            &  &  &  &  & (0.077) & (0.078) &  &  \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{OTHER\_IDENTITY\_ \\ COUNTERPROTEST}} &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.116 &  &  \\
            &  &  &  &  &  & (0.156) &  &  \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{Republican.Party} & 0.061$^{***}$ & 0.061$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.027$^{***}$ & 0.027$^{***}$ \\
            & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{Democratic.Party} & 0.386$^{***}$ & 0.386$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.083$^{***}$ & 0.083$^{***}$ \\
            & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.010) & (0.010) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{CIT\_EST\_White} & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.0002 & 0.0002 \\
            & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{CIT\_EST\_African\_ \\ American}} & 0.007$^{**}$ & 0.007$^{**}$ & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.0005 & 0.0005 \\
            & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.002) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{CIT\_EST\_NonWhite} & 0.014 & 0.014 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 \\
            & (0.011) & (0.011) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{CVAP\_EST\_White} & 0.007 & 0.007 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.001 \\
            & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.003) & (0.003) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{CVAP\_EST\_African\_ \\ American}} & $-$0.007 & $-$0.007 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.001 \\
            & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{CVAP\_EST\_NonWhite} & $-$0.020 & $-$0.020 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.002 & 0.002 \\
            & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.010) & (0.010) \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{Constant} & $-$23.099 & $-$23.099 & 5.245 & 5.245 & 5.244 & 5.241 & 1.899 & 1.898 \\
            & (14.561) & (14.561) & (12.598) & (12.599) & (12.608) & (12.609) & (8.972) & (8.972) \\
            \midrule
            Observations & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 \\
            R$^{2}$ & 0.778 & 0.778 & 0.660 & 0.660 & 0.659 & 0.659 & 0.664 & 0.664 \\
            Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.654 & 0.654 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.476 & 0.476 \\
            \multirow{2}{*}{Residual Std. Error} & \makecell[c]{0.403 \\ (df = 6145)} & \makecell[c]{0.403 \\ (df = 6144)} & \makecell[c]{0.348 \\ (df = 6145)} & \makecell[c]{0.348 \\ (df = 6144)} & \makecell[c]{0.349 \\ (df = 6145)} & \makecell[c]{0.349 \\ (df = 6144)} & \makecell[c]{0.248 \\ (df = 6145)} & \makecell[c]{0.248 \\ (df = 6144)} \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{F Statistic} & \makecell[c]{6.250$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3448; \\ 6145)} & \makecell[c]{6.249$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3449; \\ 6144)} & \makecell[c]{3.452$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3448; \\ 6145)} & \makecell[c]{3.450$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3449; \\ 6144)} & \makecell[c]{3.443$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3448; \\ 6145)} & \makecell[c]{3.442$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3449; \\ 6144)} & \makecell[c]{3.524$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3448; \\ 6145)} & \makecell[c]{3.523$^{***}$ \\ (df = 3449; \\ 6144)} \\
            \midrule
            \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{8}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\*
            \bottomrule
        \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Maybe someone else has a better approach ...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
{\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\quad}cccccccc@{}} 
\caption{your caption text here}\label{teb:key}\\
\toprule
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\midrule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{NonWhite} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Black.or.\\African.American}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
 (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{your caption text here - continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\midrule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Female} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{NonWhite} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Black.or.\\African.American}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
 (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\multicolumn{8}{l}{
 factor(ELECTORAL\_TERM)2018}\\* 
  0.104$^{***}$ & 0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.104$^{***}$ & $-$0.103$^{***}$ & $-$0.103$^{***}$ & $-$0.047$^{***}$ & $-$0.047$^{***}$ \\*
  (0.010) & (0.010) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.006) & (0.006) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{ factor(ELECTORAL\_TERM)2019}\\* 
  0.129$^{***}$ & 0.128$^{***}$ & 0.088$^{***}$ & 0.088$^{***}$ & 0.092$^{***}$ & 0.092$^{***}$ & 0.063$^{***}$ & 0.063$^{***}$ \\*
  (0.011) & (0.011) & (0.009) & (0.010) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{ WOMENS\_RIGHTS\_PROTEST}\\* 
  $-$0.016 & $-$0.025 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
  (0.018) & (0.019) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{ WOMENS\_RIGHTS\_COUNTERPROTEST}\\*
  & 0.052 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\*
  & (0.043) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{RACIAL\_PROTEST}\\* 
  &  & 0.032$^{***}$ & 0.032$^{***}$ &  &  & 0.020$^{***}$ & 0.021$^{***}$ \\*
  &  & (0.010) & (0.011) &  &  & (0.007) & (0.008) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{RACIAL\_COUNTERPROTEST}\\* 
  &  &  & 0.001 &  &  &  & $-$0.007 \\*
  &  &  & (0.039) &  &  &  & (0.028) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{OTHER\_IDENTITY\_PROTEST}\\*
  &  &  &  & 0.057 & 0.068 &  &  \\*
  &  &  &  & (0.077) & (0.078) &  &  \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{OTHER\_IDENTITY\_COUNTERPROTEST}\\* 
  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.116 &  &  \\*
  &  &  &  &  & (0.156) &  &  \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Republican.Party}\\* 
  0.061$^{***}$ & 0.061$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.068$^{***}$ & 0.027$^{***}$ & 0.027$^{***}$ \\*
  (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.009) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Democratic.Party}\\* 
  0.386$^{***}$ & 0.386$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.162$^{***}$ & 0.083$^{***}$ & 0.083$^{***}$ \\*
  (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.010) & (0.010) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{CIT\_EST\_White}\\* 
  $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.0002 & 0.0002 \\*
  (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{CIT\_EST\_African\_American}\\* 
  0.007$^{**}$ & 0.007$^{**}$ & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.0005 & 0.0005 \\*
  (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.002) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{CIT\_EST\_NonWhite}\\* 
  0.014 & 0.014 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 \\*
  (0.011) & (0.011) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.009) & (0.007) & (0.007) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{CVAP\_EST\_White}\\* 
  0.007 & 0.007 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.001 \\*
  (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.003) & (0.003) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{CVAP\_EST\_African\_American}\\* 
  $-$0.007 & $-$0.007 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.002 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.001 \\*
  (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{CVAP\_EST\_NonWhite}\\* 
  $-$0.020 & $-$0.020 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.002 & 0.002 \\*
  (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.014) & (0.010) & (0.010) \\
  \addlinespace
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Constant}\\* 
  $-$23.099 & $-$23.099 & 5.245 & 5.245 & 5.244 & 5.241 & 1.899 & 1.898 \\*
  (14.561) & (14.561) & (12.598) & (12.599) & (12.608) & (12.609) & (8.972) & (8.972) \\
  \addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Observations}\\* 
  9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 & 9,594 \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{R$^{2}$}\\*
  0.778 & 0.778 & 0.660 & 0.660 & 0.659 & 0.659 & 0.664 & 0.664 \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Adjusted R$^{2}$}\\* 
  0.654 & 0.654 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.468 & 0.476 & 0.476 \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Residual Std. Error}\\* 
  0.403  & 0.403 & 0.348  & 0.348  & 0.349 & 0.349  & 0.248  & 0.248  \\
  \textsuperscript{a} & \textsuperscript{b} & \textsuperscript{a} & \textsuperscript{b} & \textsuperscript{a} &  \textsuperscript{b} &  \textsuperscript{a} & \textsuperscript{b} \\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{F Statistic}\\* 
  6.250$^{***}$  & 6.249$^{***}$ & 3.452$^{***}$  & 3.450$^{***}$  & 3.443$^{***}$  & 3.442$^{***}$  & 3.524$^{***}$  & 3.523$^{***}$ \\
  \textsuperscript{c} & \textsuperscript{d} & \textsuperscript{c} &  \textsuperscript{d} & \textsuperscript{c} &  \textsuperscript{d} &  \textsuperscript{c} &  \textsuperscript{d} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textit{Note:} \quad \textsuperscript{a} df = 6145,  \textsuperscript{b} df = 6144,   \textsuperscript{c} df = 3448; 6145,   \textsuperscript{d} df = 3449; 6144 }\\
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\phantom{\textit{Note:} \quad}$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{longtable}} 
\end{document}
```